# back-to-back barplot with independent axes R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am wanting to plot back-to-back barplot, however each side is on an independent axes. I can plot them back to back by taking the negative of one set, but that leaves them on the same access and because pvalues are smaller their bars are barely represented.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <-structure(list(Description = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", 
    "g", "h", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), test = c("size", 
    "size", "size", "size", "size", "size", "size", "size", "p", 
    "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p"), value = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.125, 
    0.1, 0.075, 0.1, 0.075, 0.125, 0.000230705311441713, 0.000314488619269942, 
    0.00106639822095382, 0.00108290238851994, 0.00114723539549198, 
    0.00160204850890075, 0.0019276388745184, 0.00320371567547557)), .Names = c("Description", 
    "test", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

df$value[df$test == 'p'] <- -(df$value[df$test == 'p'])

ggplot(df, aes(x=Description, y= value, group=test, fill=test)) + geom_col() +coord_flip()
```

Ideally I would like each group on independent axes so that the bars meet at zero (in the middle of the plot region) but be on different scales for this example ylim would be something like ylim(0,0.13) and for pvalue c(0, 0.0035)

Comment: I'd think about whether this is a good way to represent the data. If the axes are independent, should values be drawn as though they are comparable? Perhaps a scatterplot of p versus size is a better way to convey the information?

Comment: I am seriously contemplating that, size was a poor descriptor of what my data actually is. Its basically results from hypergeometric tests, were A-H are subgroups that, in this case are over represented, size would be the ratio of items found in my data that match each subgroup compare to the total about in each subgroup. Does that make sense? I think the two plots would show nicely the significance along with the proportion of items

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using facets, and tweaking to remove the spacing between facets:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Description, y= value, fill=test)) + 
    facet_wrap(~ test, scales = "free_x") + 
    geom_col() + 
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "mm"))
```

It might create some issues with axis labels, and these would be a bit tricky to solve. In that case, it might be easier to keep some space between the facets, at the expense of not having the bars meet in the middle.

Output:

[image]

PS: you can also remove the negative axis labels with something like:

```
scale_y_continuous(
    expand = c(0, 0), 
    labels = function(x) signif(abs(x), 3)
)
```

Comment: That is great, a nice solution. Only improvement would be whether the plot window was slightly larger than the bars. I know you can independently adjust the ylim in ggplot v3 with `expand_scale` but due to having to inverse one plot the lower and upper limits of the two plots are inversed. I will happily settle for your answer though, thank you.

Comment: Yes it's tricky, I think you would need to set different limits in each facet, which I can't think how to do off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

I have adapted [this elegant solution](https://bookdown.org/lyzhang10/lzhang_r_tips_book/how-to-plot-data.html#creating-back-to-back-bar-charts) to my needs. Kudos to Lingyun Zhang.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
ten_positive_rand_numbers <- abs(rnorm(10)) + 0.1
the_prob <- ten_positive_rand_numbers / sum(ten_positive_rand_numbers)

fk_data <- data.frame(job_type = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 1000, 
                                        replace = TRUE, prob = the_prob),
                      gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 1000, 
                                      replace = TRUE))

# prepare data for plotting
plotting_df <-
  fk_data %>% 
  group_by(job_type, gender) %>% 
  summarise(Freq = n()) %>% 
  # a trick!
  mutate(Freq = if_else(gender == "Male", -Freq, Freq))
## find the order
temp_df <-
  plotting_df %>% 
  filter(gender == "Female") %>% 
  arrange(Freq)
the_order <- temp_df$job_type

# plot
p <- 
  plotting_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = job_type, y = Freq, group = gender, fill = gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.75) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = the_order) +
  # another trick!
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-150, 150, 50), 
                     labels = abs(seq(-150, 150, 50))) +
  labs(x = "Job type", y = "Count", title = "Back-to-back bar chart") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill =  "grey90")) +
  # reverse the order of items in legend
  # guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  # change the default colors of bars
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"),
                    name = "",
                    breaks = c("Male", "Female"),
                    labels = c("Male", "Female")) 
print(p)
```

It can be improved with other minor details, including `geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "black")`.

Answer (score 1):

@Marius solution is easier than this solution but this allows more control of each graph independently.

I have to removed the plot margins on the right of p1 and and left of p2. For some reason there is padding on the left margin so needed -3.5pt to bring it flush, not sure whether this will be consistent across all plots. The other manual thing is changing the breaks on one axis so 0 isn't plotted on top of each other.

I also don't need to negative the p values just use `scale_y_reverse`

```
p1 <- ggplot(df[df$test == 'p',], aes(x=Description, y= value)) + geom_col(fill='red') + theme_minimal()+
  coord_flip() + scale_y_reverse(name= "axis1",expand = expand_scale(mult= c(c(0.05,0)))) +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "mm")) +theme(plot.margin = unit(c(5.5, 0, 5.5, 5.5), "pt"))

p2 <- ggplot(df[df$test != 'p',], aes(x=Description, y= value)) + geom_col(fill='blue') + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "axis2", breaks = seq(0.025, 0.125, 0.025) ,expand = expand_scale(mult= c(c(0,0.05)))) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "mm"))+ theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, -3.5), "pt"))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(cbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2), size = "last"))
```

I have also have used `theme_minimal` but that was just for my aesthetic preference. 
[image]

Comment: that is also a neat solution, @George. Any idea how one could add axis labels to the solution I added more recently?