# How to create this chart in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I have a task a bit complicated for my knowledge in R. I need to reproduce this graphic of the figure in R, I performed several searches and could not find anything. The main thing is to be able to reproduce the graphic (it doesn't have to be identical), subtitles are not so important. Any ideas on how to do it or just using another program? Thanks!!

[image: chart model]

Comment: You should search for back-to-back barplots, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015088/back-to-back-barplot-with-independent-axes-r
Then if you are stuck on the concrete implementation, provide a reproducible example and code, what you've tried.

Comment: @kath Thanks for the reply, I will try your suggestion. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Check also the `facet_share()` function of the [`ggpol` package](https://erocoar.github.io/ggpol/), very handy for population pyramids/comparisons