# I can't have a really back-to-back bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to do a back-to-back bar plot, but it did not happen despite I use the command coord_flip(). The output consists of bars that meet in the middle of the graphic. I attached my R code:

```
Annotation_term <- c("Disulfide bond", "Secreted", "Signal peptide", "Extracellular region", "Glycoprotein", "Glycosylation site", "G protein-coupled receptor", "Transducer", "Olfaction", "Olfactory receptor", "Sensory transduction", "Receptor", "Topological extracellular domain", "Transmembrane region", "Cell membrane", "Sensory perception of smell", "Topological cytoplasmic domain", "G-protein coupled receptor signaling pathway", "Immunoglobulin", "Complement activation", "Antigen binding", "Proteolysis", "Regulation of inmune response", "Blood microparticle", "Fc-gamma receptor signaling pathway in phagocytosis", "Receptor-mediated endocytosis", "40S ribosomal protein SA", "Laminin-binding","Homeobox: DNA binding region", "Charge relay system", "Cornified envelope", "Cytokine receptor binding","Disulfide bond", "Secreted", "Signal peptide", "Extracellular region", "Glycoprotein", "Glycosylation site", "G protein-coupled receptor", "Transducer", "Olfaction", "Olfactory receptor", "Sensory transduction", "Receptor", "Topological extracellular domain", "Transmembrane region", "Cell membrane", "Sensory perception of smell", "Topological cytoplasmic domain", "G-protein coupled receptor signaling pathway", "Immunoglobulin", "Complement activation", "Antigen binding", "Proteolysis", "Regulation of inmune response", "Blood microparticle", "Fc-gamma receptor signaling pathway in phagocytosis", "Receptor-mediated endocytosis", "40S ribosomal protein SA", "Laminin-binding","Homeobox: DNA binding region", "Charge relay system", "Cornified envelope", "Cytokine receptor binding")
test <-c("Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","Genes associated","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR","FDR")
value <-c(361,242,398,247,398,365,121,122,75,73,90,149,238,392,452,77,259,121,108,27,26,53,53,27,23,27,6,6,32,26,11,6,0.000000000000000000000000000155,0.0000000000000000000000000000000184,0.00000000000000000000032300000000000004,0.00000000000181,0.000000000000000000000030800000000000004,0.00000000000000000016000000000000002,0.0000000000000000000853,0.000000000000000001,0.00000000000000029,0.0000000000000020600000000000003,0.000000000000000679,0.0000000437,0.00000000022200000000000003,0.000054199999999999996,0.0007769999999999999,0.0000041,0.000010199999999999999,0.00000000000000000147,0.007240000000000001,0.000000997,0.000000020600000000000002,0.0131,0.00147,0.0000235,0.00027,0.00163,0.00927,0.00927,0.00456,0.0111,0.00895,0.0347)
df <-data.frame(Annotation_term, test,value)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Annotation_term, y= value, fill=test)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ test, scales = "free_x") + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "mm"))
```

[image]

Comment: The solution here seems to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015088/back-to-back-barplot-with-independent-axes-r still. Did you change some of your values to negative values as was done in the data for the working example?

Comment: What Mr. Flick has suggested is more elegant, but this is what I did the last time I had to do this.

Split your data into two dataframes (by the variable test). Make a ggplot for each (and i.e. save into `g1` and `g2` and then use `grid.arrange(g1,g2)` from the `gridExtra` package to align the two ggplots, one with regular bars, the other having `coord_flip()` applied to it.

Comment: What do you mean by back-to-back? Like a [pyramid chart](https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/population_pyramid.html)? `coord_flip` flips x & y axes, not sure what else you wanted it to do

Comment: You missed an important step from the duplicate: You need some values to be negative: `df[df$test=="FDR", "value"] <- -df[df$test=="FDR", "value"]`