# add rows and values to data frame based on unmatched entries R

Tags: r, dplyr

My data resembles:

```
dataset <- c(rep("K19", 4), rep("K20", 5))
feature <- c(letters[1:4], "a", "b", "c", "e", "f")
gain <- (c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.35, 0.3, 0.18, 0.05, 0.02))
mydata <- data.frame(dataset, feature, gain)
```

K19 / K20 represent years that share some features but differ in others. To make a barplot [like the one over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015088/back-to-back-barplot-with-independent-axes-r/67247994#67247994), I need to fill in the missing features so that each year has all features `"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"`. The 'gain' value for the previously missing features should be zero, like this:

```
dataset <- c(rep("K19", 6), rep("K20", 6))
feature <- c(letters[1:6], letters[1:6])
gain <- (c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.35, 0.3, 0.18, 0.0, 0.05, 0.02))
mydata <- data.frame(dataset, feature, gain)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyr::complete()`

```r
library(tidyr)


complete(mydata, dataset, feature, fill = list(gain = 0))

#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    dataset feature  gain
#>    <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 K19     a        0.4 
#>  2 K19     b        0.3 
#>  3 K19     c        0.2 
#>  4 K19     d        0.1 
#>  5 K19     e        0   
#>  6 K19     f        0   
#>  7 K20     a        0.35
#>  8 K20     b        0.3 
#>  9 K20     c        0.18
#> 10 K20     d        0   
#> 11 K20     e        0.05
#> 12 K20     f        0.02
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**data**

```
dataset <- c(rep("K19", 4), rep("K20", 5))
feature <- c(letters[1:4], "a", "b", "c", "e", "f")
gain <- (c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.35, 0.3, 0.18, 0.05, 0.02))
mydata <- data.frame(dataset, feature, gain)
```

Comment: works on my reprex, no change to my real data. any clues please?

Comment: OK I had to dplyr::ungroup() the target.