# How can I create a horizontal bar chart in R that is split in the middle based off an additional variable on the x-axis?

Tags: r, data-visualization, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a horizontal bar chart that visualizes abundance at specified depth intervals at both day and night. Essentially for those who are familiar with diel vertical migration (dvm), I'm trying to visualize that.

Here's a [link](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Vertical-distribution-abundance-ind-m-3-and-species-composition-of-dominant-micro_fig1_305749392) to an example of what I'm talking about, specifically the bottom part of the figure. And [another](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Day-empty-bars-and-night-filled-bars-vertical-distribution-of-Daphnia-ambigua-in_fig1_262510020) one.

I've been able to get this so far

[image]

but I'd like to make the duplicates go side by side instead with the middle divider indicating the change in day vs. night. So instead of it going 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 on the y-axis it will have one set of 5-1 on the left and another set on the right, with the columns being directly side-by-side. Having one side shaded and another white would be super useful also! I'm also wondering how to add the error bars for the standard deviation too.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
abundance<-c(BroadClassification$Average[BroadClassification$BroadClassification=="Fish"])
fish<-c(BroadClassification$BroadClassification[BroadClassification$BroadClassification=="Fish"])
depth<-c(BroadClassification$ï..Net[BroadClassification$BroadClassification=="Fish"])
stdev<-c(BroadClassification$StdDev[BroadClassification$BroadClassification=="Fish"])
cols<- c(BroadClassification$DayNight[BroadClassification$BroadClassification=="Fish"])
bp1 <- barplot(abundance, main="Preliminary Broad Classification", horiz=TRUE, names.arg=depth)
```

Here is some example data

```
1  ï»¿Net,DayNight,BroadClassification,Average,StdDev
2             1,Day,Cephalopod,0.5,0.08
3             1,Day,Crustacea,2,3.2
4                  1,Day,Fish,1,4.0
5            2,Day,Cephalopod,0.6,0.1
6             2,Day,Crustacea,6,2.3
7                  2,Day,Fish,7,8.1
8            3,Day,Cephalopod,0.2,0.2
9             3,Day,Crustacea,8,2.1
10                   3,Day,Fish,9,7.1
11           4,Day,Cephalopod,1,1.0
12            4,Day,Crustacea,0.3,0.2
13                 4,Day,Fish,4,7.8
14            5,Day,Cephalopod,5.2,6.1
15            5,Day,Crustacea,0.4,0.3
16                 5,Day,Fish,1.6,2.1
17         1,Night,Cephalopod,0.1,0.2
18          1,Night,Crustacea,1.8,4.2
19               1,Night,Fish,1.4,0.7
20          2,Night,Cephalopod,0.2,0.1
21          2,Night,Crustacea,3.2,8.9
22               2,Night,Fish,14,11.1
23         3,Night,Cephalopod,0.1,0.4
24           3,Night,Crustacea,1.2,2.4
25               3,Night,Fish,7.8,10.1
26         4,Night,Cephalopod,0.3,0.8
27          4,Night,Crustacea,4.2,4.1
28               4,Night,Fish,3.1,3.1
29         5,Night,Cephalopod,0.4,0.2
30          5,Night,Crustacea,0.9,0.1
31               5,Night,Fish,1.2,1.2
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: If you're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015088/back-to-back-barplot-with-independent-axes-r), say so and I'll vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [back-to-back barplot with independent axes R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015088/back-to-back-barplot-with-independent-axes-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for :-)

The `ggplot2` and `dplyr` libraries would be useful to you! You can use `dplyr::filter` to extract all the Fish data instead of manually doing so for each variable.

Then, you can use `ggplot` to make the graph. I plotted Day with correct Average values, and the Night data with negative Average values. Then, flipped the coordinates (so the graph is verticle). Then, relabeled the y-axis since you won't want to show negative values.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

BroadClassificationFish <- BroadClassification %>% filter(BroadClassification == "Fish")

plot <- ggplot(BroadClassificationFish, aes(x = Net)) +
  geom_col(data = subset(BroadClassificationFish, DayNight == "Day"), 
           aes(y = Average, fill = 'Day')) +
  geom_col(data = subset(BroadClassificationFish, DayNight == "Night"), 
           aes(y = -Average, fill = 'Night')) + coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-20,20, by = 4),
                     labels = (c(seq(20, 0, by = -4), seq(4,20,by=4))))
  
plot
```

[image]

To add standard deviation bars, you can add the following two geometries.

```
geom_errorbar(data = subset(BroadClassificationFish, DayNight == "Day"),
                #aes(ymin = Average - StdDev, ymax = Average + StdDev)) +
geom_col(data = subset(BroadClassificationFish, DayNight == "Night"), 
           aes(y = -Average, fill = 'Night')) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

The standard deviations in the data are quite big, so it does look a little strange, unfortunately.

Comment: This is great thank you!! I have one last question, how can I move the x-axis to the top of the graph instead of the bottom? Thank you so much again!

Comment: + scale_x_discrete(position = "top")

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the second follow up, I just noticed an issue. It looks like it's using equivalent values for the 'average' for both day and night. These should be different values. For example, Net 3 during the day will have a higher average than Net 3 during night (seen in the original chart I made). Do you know why it seems to be using equivalent values? The code looks like it should have the differences but it looks equivalent. Also, do you know how I can add error bars? It should be the values in the StdDev column. I've tried using geom_errorbar but it doesn't look positioned right. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the answer above! I made an error in the subset code, so use '==' rather than '=' . Otherwise, geom_errorbar is correct,  it just may look off due to this particular data. Some other users also linked solutions to similar problems that use faceting, so that could possibly be a more elegant solution. Good luck :-)